# '08 Kia Spectra won't start after head gasket/timing belt replacement

Tags: starting, timing-belt, kia, head-gasket

We got this little KIA for a great deal with only 102k miles on it. Probably put less than 1k miles on it before the radiator split open on top, and it quit. (We were driving on the highway with cruise control on)

We replaced the radiator, and we guessed that the head gasket would need replaced also. Took it all apart, and sure enough, there was some rust and gunk in the cylinders, so we bought a gasket kit and replaced all the gaskets. This took place over a couple of months, as we found time to work on it. By now it has been about 6 months since it last ran, and we can't get it to start! It cranks just fine, and fires once in a while, but just can't quite get enough "oomph" to actually run.

We theorized that since it's been 6 months, maybe the gas was bad, so we emptied the tank as much as we could, and added 4-5 gallons of high-octane. Checked all the plugs, and we're getting spark... Double-checked the timing belt, it's aligned. Pulled a bunch of fuses and put them back in, and all of a sudden it *almost* would start! (Firing somewhat rhythmically)

After cranking for a while, now it's basically back to where it was, just cranking and cranking, with a little half-hearted attempt once in a while. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you verify your getting compression?

Comment: How/where did you verify the spark?

Comment: With as much as you would have had to take off to do all the work you claim, there are several electronic sensors and devices that would need to be plugged back in.  Make sure you don't have any loose connectors or crimped/cut wires.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about verifying compression.
@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, We removed the plug, while it was still attached to the wire, and when held close to metal, it sparked when the engine was cranked.
Yep, we checked and double checked all the wires and plugs.

Comment: Firing order ??  Is #1 correct relative to Top Dead Center? Functional crank position sensor ? (Hall effect = easy test with a volt ohm meter and screwdriver...)

Comment: I think @zipzit is onto something. Lack of cam/crank position sensor signal can cause trouble. There are a bunch of other possibilities though, as others have mentioned (fuel, air, compression, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, @zipzit, I don't quite understand what you mean.
By #1 do you mean the first piston? Where would the crank position sensor be?

Comment: Listen for the fuel pump, is it running?  I had a similar issue it turned out to be a ground wire I did not reattach. It would occasionally hit the frame and fire but only for a few seconds.

Comment: @mikes, yes we know that the fuel pump is working, we disconnected it, and gas came pouring out every time we turn the key!

Comment: Lets talk about firing order.  Assuming this is a four cylinder engine, the firing order is 1-3-4-2.. In that order.  If you swap wires anywhere and that order gets swapped = no go.   If you get the #1 wire in the wrong place, even though you have the right firing order, you may not have the correct #1 start sequence.  (in effect you'd have 3-4-2-1 or 2-1-3-4)  again, that means = no go.  You have to have the correct firing order AND the correct start timing.  Timing is based on crankshaft position (Top Dead Center) and valve timing... remember this is a four cycle engine.

Comment: You will definitely want to use a book to tell you where Top Dead Center (TDC) should be, where the distributor should be pointing at that point, and where each of the wires should be routed.  Generally you'll find a page that shows the cylinder order, the firing order, how to read TDC AND the alignment of the distributor inside the distributor cap.

Comment: Er.. wait just a minute.  Are you telling me you swapped a head gasket without having a service manual? How did you know where to torque the head bolts? Yeah, if you did that job without reference that's not good.  You are doomed to fail. If you have the manual, then you would be reading up on your own question "Where would the crank position sensor be?"  Again here's what I don't know.. Year and make --> type of distributor system, electronic with position sensors (1 or 2) or manual dist  Your repair book should show that stuff.  I suspect you've got a spark problem, related to mis-assembly.

Comment: We got torquing info from the local KIA dealer.

Comment: A $20 Chilton style manual is probably money well spent.  It will tell you a lot about how your car works.  Includes lots of troubleshooting info specifically for your make and model.  Wiring diagrams, torque numbers specs.. some include diagnostic codes.  Its also possible you can read engine codes on your vehicle with special button presses at the cluster.  The repair manual will tell you this stuff.   With the questions you are asking here this is good value.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? 
http://repair.chiltondiy.com/Pub/DIY/Product.aspx?ca=Repair&b=29060

Comment: Ugh.  That's terrible pricing.  That manual is the kind of thing you will use today, and then again 18 months from now.  Look for an actual Haynes or Chilton's paper manual.  I see AutoZone has [Haynes available on their website.](http://www.autozone.com/1/categories/kia-spectra-repair-manuals)  Oops. and the price is now just under $30, sigh.  I also see manuals on Ebay < $20

Comment: Have you tried motor starter spray? Brake cleaner or deodorant should also work

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from the comments, it seems that the issue could be a firing order problem, and that your alignment (TDC) could be out of place.

Check your manuals (or manuals online), or purchase a manual to gain this information and make sure everything follows the manual, we do not wish to have a blow out ;)

(Note: This is my thoughts and what i would do in the situation, none of this is saying that you should do so, always use appropriate tools and protective equipment where needed!)